# how to make new image picker when user tap button

Tags: flutter, dynamic, imagepicker

I want to create dynamic form that contain image picker. The number of form depends whats user tap the button, so does the image picker.

I have created this so far, but the images doesn't show up. But selected image each form (inside image picker) is saved.

initState

```
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState

    formDetails.add(addForm());
    super.initState();
  }
```

```
  var listTxtController = <TextEditingController>[];
  var listAssets = <List<Asset>>[];
  var listFiles = <List<File>>[];
  var listImages = <List<Asset>>[];

  var formDetails = <Widget>[];

addForm() {
    var txtController = TextEditingController();
    var asset0 = <Asset>[];
    var file0 = <File>[];
    List<Asset> images0 = <Asset>[];

    listTextController.add(txtController);
    listAssets.add(asset0);
    listFiles.add(file0);
    listImages.add(images0);


    Future<void> loadAssets0() async {
      List<Asset> resultList0 = <Asset>[];
      String error = 'No Error Detected';

      try {
        resultList0 = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
          //
          selectedAssets: images0,
          //,
          ),
        );
      } on Exception catch (e) {
        error = e.toString();
      }

      if (!mounted) return;

      setState(() {
        images0 = resultList0;
        _error = error;
      });
    }

    return Column(
      children: [
        customDatepicker(context, txtController),
        Divider(height: 1),
        SizedBox(height: 8),
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    AutoSizeText("Image Picker",
                        minFontSize: 8,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
                  ],
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          loadAssets0();
                        },
                        child: Container(
                            width: 20,
                            height: 20,
                           ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 5),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          _openCamera();
                        },
                        child: Container(
                            width: 20,
                            height: 20,
                            )
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        
        Visibility(
          visible: images0.length > 0? true : false,
          child: Column(
            children: [
             
              Divider(height: 8),
              Container(
                height: 100,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: GridView.count(
                    crossAxisCount: 1,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    children: List.generate(images0.length, (index) {
                      Asset asset = images0[index];
                      return AssetThumb(
                        asset: asset,
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
                      );
                    }),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

button add new form

```
  FlatButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          setState(() {
                                            formDetails
                                                .add(addForm());
                                          });
                                        },
                                        child: Text('Add Form'))
```

thanks you.
I use this packages for multi image picker
https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker/example

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69973004/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69807439/13997210)   for `ImagePicker`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But thats not what I mean. My code is working when it's use with static/only one image picker. All I want is almost the same with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64097088/16170741), but the number of image inserted is depends on user tap (not only 5, refers that answer). @RavindraS.Patil